# Reference before_body_end doesn't work - after_body_start does?

Tags: layout

Starting to think I've lost my mojo...

Both blocks named `before_body_end` and `after_body_start` are of type `core/text_list`. However, the following layout xml:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="remarketing/ecjs" name="remarketing_ecjs" as="remarketing_ecjs" />
            <block type="remarketing/modal" name="remarketing_modal" as="remarketing_modal" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Does not output the child blocks in the reference. If I swap the before_body_end for `after_body_start`, the blocks render as expected

Both child blocks extend from Mage_Core_Block_Text.

Any ideas why? I think I have Friday-osis...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This may sound stupid, but I'll ask anyway: did you double-check that the main template file (e.g. 1column.phtml) of your theme does `echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end')`?

On a vanilla CE 1.7.0.2, this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" name="test1" template="test.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="test2" template="test.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="test3" template="test.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

outputs my test block three times.

Reasons why it may show up in `after_body_start` but not in `before_body_end` from the top of my head:

1. Block is not echoed in the used main .phtml file.
2. Some code unsets `before_body_end` during building the page.
3. Some code unsets the children of `before_body_end` during building the page.

I assume a modified `page.xml` (so that the block isn't declared) or a caching issue can be ruled out given that it's you. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I've checked all of those things. `echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end')` is present... page.xml is unmodified. I will keep digging. I refuse to let this one beat me! :)

Comment: The answer in the end was a modified enterprise/default/layout/page.xml file which renamed `before_body_end` to `closure`. It was a Friday and for some reason I didn't think of enterprise/default - thanks for jogging my memory!

Comment: @Matthias Zeis  i have used "after_body_start" and now it's working for me. Thanks