# add html to all pages

Tags: module, magento-1

I am creating a module and I want it should add a .phtml files contents to all pages what do I need to write in my layout.xml file to do this? I am unsuccessfully trying,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="mypopup_block"  template="[namespace]/[module]/htmltoadd.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

here is the config.xml calling the layout file

```
<config>
...
<global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <[namespace]_[module module="[namespace]_[module">
                <file>[namespace]_[module].xml</file>
            </[namespace]_[module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</global>
```

Comment: Your xml looks good how are you adding your xml file can you verify the xml snippet your adding is being rendered

Comment: You need to put `treestone/popup/box.phtml` at Your *frontend base Package* *`(app/design/frontend/base/default/template)`* and checked

Comment: it is there already it still doesnt work

Comment: @Bobadevv I added above

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/reference-before-body-end-doesnt-work-after-body-start-does   check this maybe helpful